# Eclipse doesn't recognize Display object

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I write this code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics size = new DisplayMetrics();
display.
```

Eclipse doesn't pop up the functions of my display object. It shows these (new, nls, runnable, toarray) only:

[image]

How can I solve?

EDIT:
Here are my imports:

```
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
```

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+Space` more times?

Comment: Yes but it didn't work.

Comment: can you show us your import statements?

Comment: Have you tried to restart eclipse?

Comment: @Eri Yes, but still same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have updated to [Eclipse Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php) recently (or perhaps, even if you haven't!), make sure "Java Proposals" is ticked under "Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced"

[image]

**EDIT**: I did not notice that your code block was not within any method and just in the body of your class. Move it into `onCreate()` or some other lifecycle method and it will work.

Comment: I'm using Kepler, I ticked Java proposals but it says "No java proposals" while Ctrl+Space cycle.

Comment: Make sure the setting has been applied and maybe try a restart of eclipse as well :)

Comment: Still no luck. And I just realized that it is not an Editor problem. Because it says "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" when I use **display.getMetrics(size);**

Comment: Try initialising `display` in `onCreate()`, I'm not sure you can call `getWindowManager()` outside.

Comment: Weird that it's unchecked by default in Kepler, lucky your answer comes up when I Google for "new nls runnable toarray" :)

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/) is some good solutions regarding such issues...